# Aptitude not updating/upgrading

Tags: debian, updates, aptitude

Using aptitude is supposed to be the easiest thing in the world. but I've been messing it up somehow.  I've recently added backports and non-free to sources.list to try to get my audio working, but as I've been playing around with the sources file, `aptitude update` only seems to give an update count when it encounters an error, and then `upgrade` does nothing.  I'm pretty sure nothing's wrong with my sources file, but here it is anyway:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian squeeze main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports squeeze-backports main contrib non-free
```

Is it possible that you can't just update everything from backports??  I'm running Debian 6.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR, by default *backports* packages have lesser priority (for a reason). If you don't want to configure package pinning, the following should work:

```
sudo apt-get -t squeeze-backports [dist-]upgrade
```

or

```
sudo aptitude -t squeeze-backports [dist-]upgrade
```

However, i'd rather suggest to install only needed packages from backports, i.e.

```
sudo apt-get -t squeeze-backports install packagename
```

or

```
sudo aptitutde -t squeeze-backports install packagename
```